# Substitute characters in a string with their values?

Tags: c, string, substitution

I have a string given (a+b)&(a+c) and I have created a truth table with values of a,b, and c. Now the problem is to evaluate the logic expression by substituting a,b, and c with corresponding values from the truth table. How it can be done in C?

**Ex: a=0 b=0 c=0   r=(0+0)&(0+)=0
a=0 b=0 c=1  r=(0+0)&(0+1)=0
and so on**

The code itself looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char c,* str, *vars, **result;
    int i=0,count=0,j=0;
    unsigned long long rows;
    str = (char*) malloc(1*sizeof(char));
    vars=(char*) malloc(1*sizeof(char));
    result=(char**)malloc(1*sizeof(char));
    char values[] = {'F', 'T'};

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        str[i++] = c;
        str = (char*) realloc(str, (i+1) * sizeof(char));
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
        {
            vars[j++]=c;
            vars=(char*) realloc(vars,(j+1)*sizeof(char));
            count++;
        }
    }
    rows=1ULL<<(count);
    result=(char**)realloc(result,(rows+2)*sizeof(char));

    for (i = 0; i < rows+1; i++)
    {
        result[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(count+1));
        for (j = 0; j < count; j++)
        {
            if(i==0)
                result[i][j]=vars[j];
            else
                result[i][j]=values[(i >> j) & 1];
        }
    }

    result[0][count]='R';

    for(i=0;i<rows+1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<count+1;j++)
        {
            //do something
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the input, truth table, and expected output?

Comment: What is the input you're using? What is the desired output? Why?

Comment: @mrknva - You wrongly `count` and tabulate multiply occurring variables (`a` in the example) more than once.

Comment: `result=(char**)realloc(result,(rows+2)*sizeof(char))` is wrong; `(char)` should rather be `*result`.

Answer (score 0):

> Now the problem is to evaluate the logic expression by substituting a,b, and c with corresponding values from the truth table.

Aside from the issues mentioned in the question's comments, *substituting* alone won't do the job *to evaluate the logic expression*. The following function for example substitutes the values while evaluating the expression. (You didn't specify the general syntax of your expressions, so I chose to support combinations of the used operators and lower case variables.)

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int indx(char *s, char c) { return strchr(s, c)-s; }

char *gstr, *gvars, *vals;  // expression string, variables, value combination

char eval()
{   // evaluate expression "gstr"
    char or = 0;    // neutral element of +
    do
    {
        char and = 1;   // neutral element of &
        do
        {
            char c = *gstr++;   // get next token
            if (islower(c))
                and &= indx("FT", vals[indx(gvars, c)]);
            else
            if (c == '(')
            {   // evaluate subexpression
                and &= eval();
                c = *gstr++;    // get next token
                if (c != ')')
                    printf("error at '%c': expected ')'\n", c), exit(1);
            }
            else
                printf("error at '%c'\n", c), exit(1);
        } while (*gstr == '&' && ++gstr);
        or |= and;
    } while (*gstr == '+' && ++gstr);
    return or;
}
```

It can be called from your `main` (inserted in your code, hence the inconsistent spacing)

```
    result[0][count]='R';
    gvars = vars;   // make variable names globally accessible
    for (i = 1; i <= rows; ++i)
    {
        gstr = str, vals = result[i],   // globally accessible
        result[i][count] = values[eval()];
        while (isspace(*gstr)) ++gstr;
        if (*gstr)
            printf("error at '%c': expected end of input\n", *gstr), exit(1);
    }

    for(i=0;i<rows+1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<count+1;j++)
        {
            putchar(result[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
```

(Don't forget to put `str[i] = '\0';` after your `getchar` loop to make a null-terminated string.) Note that due to the given `for` loop counting, the order of the truth table entries is somewhat unusual in that the row with all variables `F` comes last.